# Cantidad de servicios vendido por año mes

Tags: sql-server-2008

Este query me muestra la cantidad de servicios vendidos en un rango de fecha (20160101 al 20160131), necesito saber la cantidad de servicios vendido por mes del año 2016, 2017 y 2018, ¿Cómo podría modificar este query para obtener dicha información? Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
select f.empresadestino, f.CodigoLocal, fd.CodigoProducto, max(Convert(varchar,fd.descripcion)) as NombreProducto, 
COUNT(fd.CodigoProducto) as cantidadvendida
from FACTURADETALLE as fd left join FACTURA as f on
fd.CodigoEmp=f.CodigoEmp and
fd.empresadestino=f.empresadestino and
fd.TipoDocumento=f.TipoDocumento and
fd.NumeroSerie=f.NumeroSerie and
fd.NumeroFactura=f.NumeroFactura
where f.FechaFactura between '20160101' and '20160131'
and f.SituacionFactura='10'
and fd.CodigoTipoProducto='03'
and f.CodigoLocal in ('002', '013', '012')
and f.empresadestino in ('005', '006', '011')
group by f.empresadestino, f.codigolocal,fd.CodigoProducto
order by f.empresadestino, f.codigolocal, cantidadvendida desc
```

[image: respuesta de query de ejemplo]

Answer (score 0):

puedes modificar tu where agregando una condicion con el año de tu fecha utiliza la funcion year() de sql

ejemplo:

```
where year(f.FechaFactura) >= 2016&&year(f.FechaFactura)<=2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar las funciones `year()` y `month()` para agregar las columnas de año y mes, tanto al select, agrupación y ordenamiento.

Además, cambiar la parte del `where` para incluir los 3 años que te interesan.

Por ejemplo:

```
select   f.empresadestino
       , year(f.FechaFactura) Anio
       , month(f.FechaFactura) Mes
       , f.CodigoLocal
       , fd.CodigoProducto
       , max(Convert(varchar,fd.descripcion)) as NombreProducto
       , COUNT(fd.CodigoProducto) as cantidadvendida
  from FACTURADETALLE as fd 
       left join FACTURA as f 
              on fd.CodigoEmp=f.CodigoEmp 
             and fd.empresadestino=f.empresadestino 
             and fd.TipoDocumento=f.TipoDocumento 
             and fd.NumeroSerie=f.NumeroSerie 
             and fd.NumeroFactura=f.NumeroFactura
 where year(f.FechaFactura) between 2016 and 2018
   and f.SituacionFactura='10'
   and fd.CodigoTipoProducto='03'
   and f.CodigoLocal in ('002', '013', '012')
   and f.empresadestino in ('005', '006', '011')
 group by f.empresadestino
        , year(f.FechaFactura) 
        , month(f.FechaFactura)
        , f.codigolocal
        , fd.CodigoProducto
 order by f.empresadestino
        , year(f.FechaFactura) 
        , month(f.FechaFactura)
        , f.codigolocal
        , cantidadvendida desc
```